# Ubuntu Server 14.04 suddenly stopped serving webpages

Tags: server, apache2, mail-server, certificates

I installed iRedMail and set up virtual hosts to put up my own webpage along side the iredMail installation. I also put in free certificates from StartSSL.com. Everything was working great. Then I connected one of my email accounts on my android phone, and it started complaining about no connection. And now I can't open up any of my webpages. Chrome always says the webpage took too long to respond.

The server is pingable and I can still access it through SSH. Restarting the service or the server makes no difference. I verified apache2 is running.

```
service apache2 status
 * apache2 is running
```

When I look in the apache logs, I don't even see my attempts showing up in apache2/access.log. The apache2 error.log is the same few lines over and over. (I don't think that's the problem?):

```
[Wed Apr 06 17:03:42.061888 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3136] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 06 17:07:29.206904 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3136] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Apr 06 17:07:29.477532 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3136] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Apr 06 17:07:29.479156 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3136] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Anyway, I'm at a loss. Does anybody have ideas? Or even suggestions of where I should look to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Well, after waiting a while and rebooting a 3rd time, the problem went away. I'm still annoyed that I have no idea what went wrong.